# Can I show/hide layers on Leaflet map by clicking on list item?

Tags: angular

I added some layers and now I need function which shows/hide for example `this.prosumeri` on map by clicking on list item. I am using angular 15.This is my .ts file:

```
private initMap(): void {

    const tiles = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      maxZoom: 18,
      minZoom: 8,
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
    });
    
    this.overlay = {
      "Prosumeri": this.prosumeri,
      "Potrosaci": this.potrosaci,
      "Proizvodjaci":this.proizvodjaci
  };
  this.layer = L.control.layers(undefined,this.overlay).addTo(this.mapa);

  this.mapa = L.map('map', {
    center: this.centroid,
    zoom: 13,
    layers:[tiles,this.prosumeri,this.potrosaci,this.proizvodjaci]
  });
  
  }
```

I have tried some ideas, but I only managed to remove whole layer including `this.prosumeri,this.potrosaci,this.proizvodjaci`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.